# How to remove the extra commas from a csv file?

Tags: r, csv, arules

I was trying to use a csv file in R in `read.transactions()` command from [arules](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/) package.

The csv file when opened in Notepad++ shows extra commas for every non-existing values. So, I'm having to manually delete those extra commas before using the csv in `read.transactions()`. For example, the actual csv file when opened in Notepad++ looks like:

```
D115,DX06,Slz,,,,
HC,,,,,,
DX06,,,,,,
DX17,PG,,,,,
DX06,RT,Dty,Dtcr,,
```

I want it to appear like below while sending it into `read.transactions()`:

```
D115,DX06,Slz
HC
DX06
DX17,PG
DX06,RT,Dty,Dtcr
```

Is there any way I can make that change in `read.transactions()` itself, or any other way? But even before that, we don't get to see those extra commas in R(that output I showed was from Notepad++)..

So how can we even remove them in R when we can't see it?

Comment: In CSV 'Each record "should" contain the same number of comma-separated fields.' ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) so file with "removed" commas is *not* a valid CSV. Also notice that **we don't know** what `read.transactions()` function is, so we cannot help you with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to create a new file without the trailing commas is:

```
file_lines <- readLines("input.txt")
writeLines(gsub(",+$", "", file_lines),
           "without_commas.txt")
```

In the `gsub` command, `",+$"` matches one or more (`+`) commas (`,`) at the end of a line (`$`).

Since you're using Notepad++, you could just do the substitution in that program: Search > Replace, replace `,+$` with nothing, Search Mode=Regular Expression.